# Sinatra serving images in HTML

Tags: html, ruby, image, sinatra, public-folders

So I currently have a very simple Sinatra server. I have a `public` folder that has css, js, and images as folders within it. In my view when I try to do something like `<img src="/images/blah.png">`, I get a 404 response. I thought the default of the public folder is `public`. I feel like I'm not including something or doing something stupid. I am using bootstrap and the css & js files are served fine. It isn't clear to me why I'm getting this 404 with the images?

This is how I'm running my application

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)
require 'load_test_ui.rb'

unless ARGV[0].nil?
  class LoadTestUI < Sinatra::Base
    set :port, ARGV[0]
  end
end

LoadTestUI.run!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a stupid mistake; I wasn't URI encoding the source. When I changed the name to just blah.png, it rendered correctly!